# Where did this dungeon come from that was spiral shaped and contained a statue of Dagon?

Tags: dnd-5e, product-identification, dungeon

I remember there being a dungeon for D&D 5e, possibly as part of an AL adventure (I don't remember it being in a full published adventure like *Out of the Abyss*, etc), but if it was AL, I don't remember which season (probably one of the earlier ones, though), or exactly how long ago it was. Me thinking it might have been AL might be a red herring.

It was a small dungeon, I feel like it only had 8 rooms or so, arranged in a spiral shape, and near the centre of the dungeon, I want to say area 7 but that might be wrong, there was a little alcove-like room with a shrine to [Dagon](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dagon) there, and possibly a dead/undead creature or two in there. After this room, there was then the centre of the spiral, which contained the "boss fight" (I can't remember what this boss fight was either).

I can't remember what Tier this was for, but it was probably Tier 1, or Tier 2 at most; I don't think it was higher level content.

That's all I remember, although comment-questions may prompt me to remember a little more...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The Jade Temple in Secrets of the Sokol Keep in AL season 1 (DDEX 1-2)

[You can find "Secrets of Sokol Keep" here on DMsGuild.](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170405/DDEX102-Secrets-of-Sokol-Keep-5e) Part 3: The Jade Temple (starting on p. 17) describes the dungeon you're thinking of:

- It has a spiral shape
- Area 6 contains a magical jade idol that (supposedly) depicts Dagon
  in the center.

Comment: That's the one! So it was the Tyranny of Dragons season (glad me remembering that it was AL wasn't a red herring after all). Looking at it now, the dungeon has 7 rooms (not 8), and the alcove-like room I remembered was room 6 (not 7, because room 7 was the "boss fight" room in the centre of the spiral). But yes, this was the exact one I remembered. Thanks! I'm currently all out of votes for the day, so I'll have to upvote this tomorrow.

Comment: Here's a link to it on DMsGuild, if anyone's interested: https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170405/DDEX102-Secrets-of-Sokol-Keep-5e